# Pandas select via integer slicing vs integer list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I do not understand the difference between the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,5,6],[7,8,9]])
frame2 = frame.loc[[0,1]]
frame2.loc[1,1] = -99
```

and

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[1,5,6],[7,8,9]])
frame2 = frame.loc[:2]
frame2.loc[1,1] = -99
```

Why referencing via integer list does not change the original variable "frame" in contrast to referencing via integer slicing?

Comment: `frame.loc[[0,1]]` will match the labels `0` and `1` in the index whereas `frame.loc[:2]` slices `0` up untill `2`